# What are the malleability properties of block device encryption with multiple modes of operation?

Tags: modes-of-operation, disk-encryption, malleability

When encrypting a block device with a given symmetric cipher with a 128-bit block size in CBC mode, every second plaintext block in a sector can be changed to contain arbitrary data, with the blocks in between being corrupted. When encrypting with XTS mode on the other hand, an attacker has the ability to corrupt an arbitrary block of data.

Now my question is, what do the properties become when encrypting once with XTS, and once with CBC as in *aes-xts(aes-cbc(plaintext))*, assuming mutually independent keys? Is it limited to the least malleable mode (XTS in this case), so that this chain would have the same malleability properties as XTS, or is the interaction more complicated?